# Does $f(f(x)) = x \Rightarrow f$ is bijective apply?

Tags: functions

As far as I remember a reverse function for some function $f$ exists iff an inverse function exists.

Can I therefore follow from $f(f(x)) = x$ ($f$ is its own inverse function) for some function $f$ that it is bijective without proving it is injective and surjective?

Example:

$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},\ f(x) = 5 - x$

Comment: What's the domain of $f$? Is it the full codomain $Y$?

Comment: $f$ is bijective for $f: X\to Y$ iff $Y\subset X$

Comment: @kingW3 what if $Y \subseteq X$?

Comment: @muffel As far as I know, it is customary to use the notation $\subset$ to denote _weak_ set inclusion. Personally, I find it annoying and I always use $\subseteq$, but even the most respected mathematicians use $\subset$ with no reservations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This depends on the domain and codomain chosen for the function. For example, suppose that $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}$ is defined by $f(x) = x$. Then $f(f(x)) = x$ for every $x \in \Bbb{R}$, but $f$ is not a bijection since it is certainly not surjective. You can say, however, that if $x \neq y$ are both in the domain of $f$, then $f(x) \neq f(y)$ since otherwise $f(f(x)) = f(f(y)) \implies x = y$.

Comment: Nice counterexample!

Comment: I'm not convinced: see my answer.

Comment: How does "$f(f(x))$" make sense in this case? The domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I see; you're defining $\mathbb{R}$ as the subset of $\mathbb{C}$ with zero imaginary part.

Comment: @Neal Yes! That is true. I certainly consider $\Bbb{R} \subset \Bbb{C}$.

Comment: @Tom When speaking precisely, I don't usually consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, but it's a reasonable definition.

Comment: @Neal If we don't consider $\Bbb{R} \subseteq \Bbb{C}$ then the statement $f(x) = x$ in my example doesn't even make sense. However, for the purposes of this counterexample, I think that assuming $\Bbb{R} \subseteq \Bbb{C}$ isn't unreasonable.

Answer (score 7):

Since *f(f(x))* exists it implies that *f(x)* must be in the domain of *f* (else we can't form $f(f(x))$. So *f* must map some set A to itself, i.e. $f:A \rightarrow A$. Examples using say R and C are therefore not valid: the domain of *f* is either R or C, in this case you would have $f: R \rightarrow C$ and $F: C \rightarrow R$ with $f = F|_R$ (i.e. *f* is $F$ restricted to R), and then $F(f(x)) = x$.

In general if $f:A \to B$ and $F:B \to A$ then $f = F \implies B = A$, and here $f = F$ is implied by $f(f(x)) = x$.

So with that understanding then ***f* is a bijection.**

1. *f* must be onto (surjective) since for all $x \in A$ $f(x) $ is defined (under normal understanding)  and $=x$, so for all $x \in A$ there exists $x \in A$ such that $x = f(x)$
2. *f* must be into (injective) as $f(y) = y$ so if $f(x) = f(y)$ then $x = y$.

Comment: Consider $f : \{0\} \to \{0\} \cup A$ where $A$ is your favorite set; define the rule of $f$ by $f(0) = 0$. In this case $f \circ f$ makes sense because the domain of $f$ is a subset of the range (not codomain) of $f$. Moreover $f(f(x)) = x$ for all $x \in \{0\}$.

Comment: @Tom. If *f* is a well defined function then it must have a corresponding domain: what is the domain in your example, is it {0} or is it {0} $\cup A$ ? - it can't be both.

Comment: I absolutely agree the domain is not both $\{0\}$ and $\{0\} \cup A$! The domain of $f$ is $\{0\}$. The range of $f$ is $f(\{0\}) = \{0\} \subset \{0\} \cup A$. Therefore, it makes sense to write the composition of $f$ with itself since the range of $f$ is a subset of the domain of $f$.

Comment: @Tom Then *f* is a bijection from {0} to {0}, yes ?

Comment: If $f:A\rightarrow B$ then $B\subseteq A$ is enough for each $f(x)$ to be in the domain of $f$. It is not necessary that $B=A$. If $\iota: B\rightarrow A$ is the inclusion of $B$ then $\iota\circ f:A\rightarrow A$. This function is the same as $f$ if and only if $A=B$ (then $\iota$ is the identity).

Comment: @Tom It's generally assumed that $f: A \rightarrow B$ means all of A. So in the absence of any statement to the contrary it's reasonable to assume that $f:B \rightarrow A$ would mean all of B. Hence, in this case, B = A.

Comment: By "all of $A$", I assume you mean that if $f: A \to B$, then the domain of $f$ is $A$. This is correct. However, $f \circ f$ is defined as long as the *range* of $f$ is a subset of the domain of $f$. In other words, you don't need $f$ to be defined on all of $B$ for $f \circ f$ to be defined, just just need $f$ to be defined on $f(A) \subseteq B$. In general, if $h : A \to B$ and $g : C \to D$, then $g \circ h$ is defined whenever $h(A) \subseteq C$; this does not imply that $B \subseteq C$.

Comment: @Tom  $g \circ h$ is defined whenever $h(A) \subseteq C$, but it's still implicit that for $g : C \to D$ then *C* is the domain of *g*.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $f: A \to A$...

If $f \circ g$ is bijective, then $f$ is a surjective and $g$ is injective. Here, $f \circ f$ is a bijective (in fact it is the identity mapping), so $f$ is surjective and $f$ is injective. Therefore, $f$ is bijective.

Comment: The domain of $f$ is relevant as $f \circ f$ is only a bijection on the domain of $f$ - this does not tell you anything about surjectivity on the whole codomain.

Comment: Right. Fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

The self-inverse property implies injectivity but not surjectivity.

Comment: if $f:X\to X$ then $f(f(x))=x$ clearly implies surjectivity.

Comment: @user126154 Why do you assume that the domain and codomain are both the common set $X$?

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is injective, because if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $x=f(f(x))=f(f(y))=y$.

$f$ is surjective because every $x$ is the image of some $y$, namely $f(f(x))=x$ (provided that the image is the same set as the domain).

So... yes.

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: The proof goes through and $f$ is surjective as long as the codomain is a subset of the domain.

Comment: @triple_sec if the domain is a finite set then the codomain needs to be exactly the domain, however. Just a note ;P

Comment: @DanZimm True, but this is implied by the condition $f(f(x))=x$. In this case, $x\in\text{Dom}$ implies that $f(f(x))=x$, so $x\in f(\text{Dom})\subseteq\text{Codom}$, so $\text{Dom}\subseteq\text{Codom}$. In fact, I just realized that it must be true for an arbitrary non-empty domain. So, to refine, the result goes through as long as $\text{Dom}=\text{Codom}.$

Comment: @DanZimm What's wrong with the function $f : \{0\} \to \Bbb{R}$ where $f(0) = 0$? The codomain is $\Bbb{R}$, which is not even finite. Note that $f(f(x)) = x$ for every $x$ in the domain of $f$.

Comment: @Tom In your example, the codomain is not a subset of the domain, so $f$ will not be surjective, indeed.

Comment: @triple_sec Ah.. I misunderstood DanZimm's comment; I thought the suggestion was that if $f(f(x)) = x$ then the domain and codomain are forced to be equal in the finite case..! My apologies.

Comment: @Tom I guess DanZimm meant that for a finite domain, the codomain needs to equal it _for surjectivity to hold_. I think this should be required for arbitrary non-empty domains as well.

Comment: You should start the second line with: 'in general $f$ is *not* surjective...' and eventually continue with something like: 'however, in special case that the image is the same set as the domain...' Then I will withdraw my downvote and make it an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You have plenty of answers and according to my view you accepted one
that is indeed okay. I just want to mention a subtle point here. Your
condition was: $$\forall x\; f\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=x$$ and
under that condition $f$ is injective but does not have to be surjective.

If it would have been
slightly different: $$\forall x\; f\circ f\left(x\right)=x$$ then you are dealing with something else. This condition can only 'make sense' if
function $f\circ f$ is indeed defined. That means that its domain and
codomain must be the same. So then the answer
would have been: yes, $f$ is a bijection.

The first condition is not equivalent with: $f$ is its own inverse (as you argued in your question). The second condition is.